# Emacs: delete-selection-mode not replacing region when yanking

Tags: emacs

I'm using `delete-selection-mode`, and everything works fine when having an active region and typing or deleting. However, if I have an active region and then yank the region is not replaced. Instead the yanked text is simply inserted at point.

Is there any additional settings that I should use together with delete-selection-mode, or how do I make it replace the active region when yanking?